# How can we add Event Listener for Native Query in Spring Boot 2.0?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, event-listener

Currently, I have a scenario where I want to add event listener for executed query.

My EntityListener

```
public class EntityListener implements PostInsertEventListener, PostUpdateEventListener, PostDeleteEventListener {
```

My repository

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE example e SET e.name = :name WHERE e.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    void testUpdatedQuery(@Param("name") String name, @Param("id") String id);
```

The event listener is working fine if I use methods of spring-data-jpa, but if I try the native query above I won't able to trigger the event. So, my question is how can I listen "native query" event ?

Thanks

Comment: search datasource proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, my question is how can I listen "native query" event?

You can't at least not in a way that is similar to an EntityListener. 
The reason for this is that there is no way to determine the affected entities for a given update.

I see the following options:

1. Implement the a custom methods that uses the same where clause to load the affected entities and then trigger some kind of event mechanism.
2. as Zorglube suggested you can also use a datasource proxy to intercept every SQL query but this is likely to be to low level for your use-case sind you'll see tons of statements that you probably don't care about as those created by your JPA implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Jens, because I want to leverage this EventListener to do audit-trail whenever the application save/update database but I guess I cannot do it for "native query". So, I come with the idea that if in case I use native query (only choice) then I have to get the old object before execute query and get the new object after executed query. I know it's not a good solution but that is the only option I can think of right now.